# Iterate over a csv and change the values of a column that meets a condition

Tags: bash, sed

I have to use bash to iterate over a CSV file and replace the values of a column that meets a condition. Finally, the results have to be stored in an output file.

I have written this code, which reads the file and stores the content in an array. On iterating over the file, if the value at column 13 is equal to "NULL" then the value of this record has to be replaced by "0". Once the file is reviewed the output with the replaced values is stored at file_b.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="./2022_Accidentalidad.csv"
while IFS=; read -ra array
do
    if [[ ${array[13]} == "NULL" ]]; then
    echo "${array[13]}" | sed -n 's/NULL/0/g' 
    fi
done < $file > file_b.csv
```

The problem is that file_b is empty. Nothing is written there.
How could I do this?

I cannot use AWK, and have to use or a FOR or a WHILE command to iterate over the file.

Sample input:

```
num_expediente;fecha;hora;localizacion;numero;cod_distrito;distrito;tipo_accidente;estado_meteorológico;tipo_vehiculo;tipo_persona;rango_edad;sexo;cod_lesividad;lesividad;coordenada_x_utm;coordenada_y_utm;positiva_alcohol;positiva_droga
2022S000001;01/01/2022;1:30:00;AVDA. ALBUFERA, 19;19;13;PUENTE DE VALLECAS;Alcance;Despejado;Turismo;Conductor;De 18 a 30 años;Mujer;NULL;NULL;443359,226;4472082,272;N;NULL
```

Expected output

```
num_expediente;fecha;hora;localizacion;numero;cod_distrito;distrito;tipo_accidente;estado_meteorológico;tipo_vehiculo;tipo_persona;rango_edad;sexo;cod_lesividad;lesividad;coordenada_x_utm;coordenada_y_utm;positiva_alcohol;positiva_droga
2022S000001;01/01/2022;1:30:00;AVDA. ALBUFERA, 19;19;13;PUENTE DE VALLECAS;Alcance;Despejado;Turismo;Conductor;De 18 a 30 años;Mujer;0;NULL;443359,226;4472082,272;N;NULL
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to use `sed`? Just do `echo 0`, since `NULL` is the entire value of `$array[13]`.

Comment: You're only echoing the rows that have `NULL` in that field. And you're only echoing that field, not the whole line.

Comment: The `-n` option to `sed` prevents it from printing anything unless you add `p` after the `s` command. Why did you use that option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `sed`. Just replace `$array[13]` with `0`. Then print the entire array with `;` separators between the fields.

```
(             # in a subshell
    IFS=';'   # set IFS, that affects `read` and `"${array[*]}"`
    while read -ra array
    do
        if [[ ${array[13]} == "NULL" ]]; then
            array[13]=0
        fi
        echo "${array[*]}"
    done
) < $file > file_b.csv
```

`echo` uses the first character of `$IFS` as the output field separator.

Comment: I'm adding some changes for proper IFS handling

Comment: I'm trying to update the last column using the same instruction ```if [[ ${array[18]} == "NULL" ]]; then array[18]=0 ; fi``` but it's not updating the file. I have also tried with ```if [[ ${array[@]:  -1} == "NULL" ]]; then array[18]=0 ; fi``` but it is not working either. Any clue?

Comment: Make sure the file doesn't have `CRLF` line breaks. If it does, the last character of `$array[18]` will be `\r` so it won't match `NULL`.. Use `dos2unix filename` to fix the file.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem with this sentence ```sed -i '1,$ s/NULL/0/g' file_b.csv```

Comment: That will replace `NULL` with `0` in all fields, not just fields 13 and 18.

Comment: This don't work, if the CVS contains text with line breaks. In this case the logical line is split into 2 or more physical lines and `read` is broken. Use the special functions of e.g. php or python to scan CVS files correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When `awk` is also possible:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR==2 && $14=="NULL"{$14=0} {print}' "$file" > file_b.csv
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, **OFS**, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: he said he's not allowed to use `awk`.

Comment: @Barmar: I had overlooked that.

Comment: This don't work, if the CVS contains text with line breaks. In this case the logical line is split into 2 or more physical lines. Use the special functions of e.g. php or python to scan CVS files correctly.

Comment: @Wiimm: Yes, this case should be kept in mind.

Answer (score 1):

One idea using a regex and the `BASH_REMATCH` array:

```
regex='(([^;]*;){13})(NULL)(;.*)'

while read -r line
do
    [[ "${line}" =~ $regex ]] && 
    line="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}0${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"

    # uncomment following line to display contents of BASH_REMATCH[] array
    # declare -p BASH_REMATCH

    echo "${line}"

done < file.csv > file_b.csv
```

This generates:

```
$ cat file_b.csv
num_expediente;fecha;hora;localizacion;numero;cod_distrito;distrito;tipo_accidente;estado_meteorológico;tipo_vehiculo;tipo_persona;rango_edad;sexo;cod_lesividad;lesividad;coordenada_x_utm;coordenada_y_utm;positiva_alcohol;positiva_droga
2022S000001;01/01/2022;1:30:00;AVDA. ALBUFERA, 19;19;13;PUENTE DE VALLECAS;Alcance;Despejado;Turismo;Conductor;De 18 a 30 años;Mujer;0;NULL;443359,226;4472082,272;N;NULL
```

Comment: This don't work, if the CVS contains text with line breaks. In this case the logical line is split into 2 or more physical lines and `read` is broken. Use the special functions of e.g. php or python to scan CVS files correctly.